# Multiprocessing clipping Python rasterio/rioxarray

Tags: clip, parallel-processing, rioxarray

Clipping a raster often takes a larger percentage of my computation time, therefore I want to try it in parallel.

I tried multiprocessing with Python's multiprocessing or pathos. But I often either does not serialize, or runs out of RAM (eventhough I set the from_disk parameter to try)

One example of my attempts is:

```py
import dill
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from xarray import DataArray
from geopandas import read_file
from rioxarray import open_rasterio
from itertools import repeat

from pathos.pools import ProcessPool


def clip(raster: DataArray, geo: Polygon):
    return raster.rio.clip([geo, ], from_disk=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    input_raster_path = r"path to .tif"
    municipalities_vector_path = r"path to.shp"

    municipalities_areas = read_file(municipalities_vector_path)
    freiland_r = open_rasterio(input_raster_path).astype('uint8')
    args = repeat(freiland_r), municipalities_areas.geometry[0:10]
    p = ProcessPool(processes=2)

    local_freiland_pvs = list(p.map(dill.copy(clip), *args))
```

Comment: What do you want to get out of this process? The rasters in memory as arrays or output as files on disk?

Comment: Well, problem with in memory is, to load the whole raster for every polygon (over 400) into the memory.  Could this be circumvented? Saving to disk, removes the problem, but takes som extrea time for saving and loading. But I would not mind, because anything would be faster. Clipping is about 98 % of my computation time.

Answer (score 0):

To do multiprocessing/multithreading with rasterio you need to pass around the path.
https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/concurrency.html

I would recommend opening the file in each thread and writing the results to disk in the thread and pass back the path to the file instead of the xarray object.

```py
def clip(input_raster_path: str, geo: Polygon):
    raster = open_rasterio(input_raster_path).rio.clip([geo], from_disk=True).astype("uint8")
    output_path = "..."
    clipped.rio.to_raster(output_path)
    return output_path
```

Comment: I changed it a bit to: ```def clip(input_raster_path: Path, name: str,  geo: Polygon):
    raster = open_rasterio(input_raster_path).rio.clip([geo], from_disk=True).astype("uint8")
    output_path = input_raster_path.parent / f"{input_raster_path.stem}_{name}{input_raster_path.suffix}"
    raster.rio.to_raster(output_path)

    return output_path``` the problem is, that I can't pickle that.

Comment: You shouldn't need to pickle it, just pass around the string form of the path.